# Why is everything displayed in master window instead of particular frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I started creating GUI that I'll use for testbench for electrical engines. My question is why is everything displayed in master window like this?:

[image: everything displayed]

Instead of the two frames?

The first time I wrote it, it was working perfectly:

[[image: first time[2]]

but then I wanted to rearrange the code using classes and the problem appeared. I'm using Python 3.7.

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Lintebench():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Linte^2 testbench")
        self.master.geometry('1000x600')

    #FRAMES
        frame = Frame(master, bg='#3e646c').place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.4, rely=0.6)
        frame2 = Frame(master, bg='#3e646c').place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.4, rely=0.6, relx=0.2)

    #FRAME 1
        self.start_button = Button(frame, text="Start", padx=50, pady=50, bg='green', activebackground='grey', command=self.start_engine).pack()
        self.stop_button = Button(frame2, text="Stop", padx=50, pady=50, bg='red', activebackground='grey', command=self.stop_engine).pack()

    #FRAME 2
        self.parameters = Label(frame2, text="PARAMETERS", font=("Arial", 16), fg='white', bg='#3e646c').place(relx=0)
        self.set_parameter = Label(frame2, text="SET", font=("Arial", 16), fg='white', bg='#3e646c').place(relx=0.8)
        self.values = Label(frame2, text="VALUES", font=("Arial", 16), fg='white', bg='#3e646c').place(relx=0.4)
        self.torque = Label(frame2, text="TORQUE", font=("Arial", 12), fg='white', bg='#3e646c').place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2)
        self.velocity = Label(frame2, text="VELOCITY", font=("Arial", 12), fg='white', bg='#3e646c').place(relx=0.7, rely=0.6)

    #parameters to set
        self.set_torque = Scale(frame2, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200).place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)
        self.set_velocity = Scale(frame2, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200).place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7)

    def start_engine(*args):
        messagebox.showinfo('Information','Engine was started')

    def stop_engine(*args):
        messagebox.showinfo('Information','Engine was stopped')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    lintebench = Lintebench(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()here
```

Comment: Please provide your code in the question as text. Don't use screenshots or links to other sites hosting your code.

Comment: Have you looked at the values of your frame variables to see if they are what you think they are?

Comment: Read up on [tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750)

Comment: It is because `frame` and `frame2` are None because they are assigned the result of `place(...)`, not `Frame(...)`.  You have chained `Frame(...)` with `place(...)`.  Separate them into two statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have chained `Frame(...)` with `place(...)` and so `frame` and `frame2` will be `None`.  Separate the chained statement into two statements:

```
frame = Frame(master, bg='#3e646c')
frame.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.4, rely=0.6)
frame2 = Frame(master, bg='#3e646c')
frame2.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.4, rely=0.6, relx=0.2)
```

Actually you need to separate all the chained statements in your code if you want to reference the widgets in other place.

Also `self.stop_button` should be child of `frame`, not `frame2`:

```
self.stop_button = Button(frame, text="Stop", padx=50, pady=50, bg='red', activebackground='grey', command=self.stop_engine)
self.stop_button.pack()
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe is becuase you're asigning their master as root, and you only have one root and when you make `roo.mainloop()` that makes them focus.